# rails 6 upgrade and FixtureSet seems fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Upgrading from Rails 4 to Rails 6.

All the cucumber tests start to fail after upgrading.

At the beginning of all the test scenarios, i am using

```
ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures(fixtures_folder, fixtures)
```

to generate the mock test data. And I tested the code with rails console, i can successfully get all the table/data in fixture files.

However, if I start a real scenario test run, the test is not able to find the related data in table. (actually the table is empty at all)

i tried

```
 pp(ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures(fixtures_folder, fixtures))
```

to make sure the fixtureSet works before each scenario.

Comment: It is not recommended to skip Rails versions when upgrading. You do not even want to skip point releases, let alone major releases. You will want to upgrade first to Rails 5.0, then 5.1, then 5.2 and only then should you attempt an upgrade to Rails 6.0.

Comment: yeap... thanks for the recommendation.... actually it is a team project and don't have enough time to upgrade one by one...